# How can we change method name of a magento module?

Tags: php, magento

How can we change method name of a magento module.

ie, I have a module to delivery products by dates to customers. Its config.xml defines method name as

```
 <default>
        <carriers>
          <deliverybydate>
               <active>0</active>
               <model>deliverybydate/carrier_deliverybydate</model>
               <title>Delivery date of your choice</title>
               <name>Delivery By Date</name>
               <deliveridatenote>Delivery on date of your choice</deliveridatenote>
               <deliverydate>1</deliverydate>
               <deliverytime>0</deliverytime>
               <deliverydatetoday>0</deliverydatetoday>
               <deliverydaterange>7</deliverydaterange>
               <deliverytimerange>08.00-09.00 AM,</deliverytimerange>
               <price>10.00</price>
               <specificerrmsg>This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us.</specificerrmsg>
            </deliverybydate>
         </carriers>
    </default>
```

How can we change the `<name>Delivery By Date</name>` dynamically. I searched for a while, but didnt got any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look in the admin under the tab

```
System -> Configuration -> Shipping methods
```

to change the name and other settings for the shipping methods.

The configuration you're showing us here are the default settings for the given shipping method. When a configuration is added (from the system.xml) it will look in the config.xml for the default settings it should put in there.

**If this doesn't work immediately, empty your cache!**

Comment: Yea got it! I forgot that, the elements under default tag can be edited by admin! just newbie to magento... thats y.. :)